# Order by count not sorting the records correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am using MySQL. I have two table i have attached the images of the both tables? When i apply ORDER by Count then the query retrieving result's from database but  not sorting them correctly, i don't know what wrong i am doing? i searched some similar question in stack overflow but still i am facing the same problem.
[image: This is the table for groups]

[image: This is the table for the group member]

I tried these but no success

```
    $sql    = "Select * from gr_groups";
    $result = $db->select($sql);
    for($j = 0; $j < count($result); $j++)
    {
        $mygrp_id = $result[$j]['id'];

        $query       = "Select * from gr_group_memberships where group_id =".$mygrp_id." ORDER BY COUNT(receiver_id) DESC";
        $exec_query  = $db->select($query);
        echo $exec_query[0]['group_id'];
    }
```

Thanks in advance?

Comment: @b0s3 i have to order the groups having more member's on the top, for that reason i am counting the the member's and then sorting them according to the count

Comment: You want `gr_group_memberships` for a `group` to show the row with highest `receiver_id` first?

Comment: Yes suppose in gr_group_member ship a group has 5 receiver_id's and another has 4 then i want the 5 be on top?

Comment: Ohk. then you are doing it wrong way.

Comment: @b0s3 what will be the right way?

Comment: When you are using `where group_id =".$mygrp_id."` it will fetch for that group only. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81254/discussion-between-mohit-and-b0s3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT count(receiver_id) as total_receiver FROM gr_group_memberships
INNER JOIN gr_group on gr_group_memberships.group_id = gr_group.id
GROUP BY gr_group_memberships.receiver_id
ORDER BY gr_group_memberships.receiver_id DESC
```

I think it will worked what you want

Comment: I am tired of this so my brain has stopped working? When i directly paste this query to sql query window it's working but when i integrate it to php code it's not?

Comment: When we print the total_receiver then it's giving 3,1,1 which is correct but when we print the group_id then that's gives 25,25,25

Comment: can you integrate it with my php code which is in the question

Comment: because we group by `receiver_id` and count it. but `receiver_id` not equal `group_id`. thats why 'group_id' did not show correctly :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81261/discussion-between-mohit-and-nahid-bin-azhar).

Answer (score 1):

Only

```
ORDER BY receiver_id DESC
```

will solve the problem.

**Update**

Try with joining them -

```
SELECT * FROM gr_groups g 
LEFT JOIN gr_group_memberships gm on gm.group_id = g.id
ORDER BY COUNT(gm.receiver_id) DESC
```

This will fetch the groups with all memberships ordering by the count.

Comment: Taking only the highest one not the other?

Comment: *highest one not the other* ??

Comment: Five groups , the group whose id is 25 has 3 member's and second group has 2 member's and the rest 3 groups have 1 member each. I want to arrange that is this order, 25 ,22,24,21 ....

Comment: So what are you getting now?

Comment: I am getting only 25 , having the maximum members

Comment: That should not happen. Can you add the updated code?

Comment: Where have you added the code.? Try to run the updated query in phpmyadmin and see what you are getting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81260/discussion-between-mohit-and-b0s3).

Answer (score 1):

Try as below;

```
$query = "Select * from gr_group_memberships where group_id = ".$mygrp_id." ORDER BY receiver_id DESC";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have the count and order by but in this way it will be better

```
 SELECT *,count(receiver_id) as total_receivers 
  FROM gr_group_memberships 
  WHERE group_id =".$mygrp_id." 
  GROUP BY receiver_id
  ORDER BY receiver_id DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
$query = "Select a.* from gr_group_memberships a 
          join( select receiver_id,count(receiver_id) as count1
          from  gr_group_memberships group by receiver_id) b on
          a.receiver_id=b.receiver_id  where a.group_id =".$mygrp_id."
          ORDER BY count1 DESC";
```

Comment: You can try this ORDER BY receiver_id DESC